# Как выровнять по ширине хлебные крошки?

Tags: css

Имеется список хл.крошек, нужно этот список выровнять по всей ширине, но не получается выровнять. Если ширина одного элемента не влазит сбоку другого, то элемент начинается с новой строки.
Нужен перенос по словам, а сейчас переносится по всему содержимому li.
Т.е. нужно, чтобы не было справа пустого места 
https://jsfiddle.net/jvnz026d/1/

```css
.top-cats li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.top-cats a {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  display: inline-block;
  background: none;
  font: 13px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #484848;
  padding: 2px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.top-cats a:first-letter{text-transform: uppercase;}
ul{padding:0}
```

```html
<ul class="top-cats">
  <li>Профессиональная химия</li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/mojuschie_i_opolaskivajuschie_sredstva">ОПОЛАСКИВАЮЩИЕ СРЕДСТВА</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/ruchnaja_mojkazamachivanie_posudy">РУЧНАЯ МОЙКА И ЧИСТКА ПОСУДЫ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/udalenie_izvestkovogo_naleta">УДАЛЕНИЕ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/ochistka_teplovogo_oborudovanija">ОЧИСТКА ТЕПЛОВОГО ОБОРУДОВАНИЯ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/ochistka_dezifektsija_i_uhod_za_poverhnostjami">ОЧИСТКА, ДЕЗИФЕКЦИЯ И УХОД ЗА ПОВЕРХНОСТЯМИ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/sanitarnye_mojuschie_sredstva">САНИТАРНЫЕ МОЮЩИЕ СРЕДСТВА</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/professionalnaja_himija_winterhalter">химия Winterhalter</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/dopolnitelnye_sredstva_dlja_uhoda">ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ СРЕДСТВА ДЛЯ УХОДА</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Добавьте `display: inline` всем, кто должен переносится по словам (`li` и `a` как минимум) и будет по словам

Comment: супер,благодарю

Comment: @andreymal, кстати для inline-элемента нельзя применить свойство :first-letter, можно ли это как-то обойти? т.е. чтобы сделать каждый li с большой буквы

Comment: Я боялся, что вы это спросите) Но есть опасение, что никак, а что мешает написать нужный регистр прямо в html-коде?

Comment: Всё нормально, этот вопрос не так важен как первый, просто хотелось уточнить

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое замечательное свойство `word-wrap: break-word`. И почему вы для `li` и `a` используете `display: inline-block`, а не `display:inline`?

```css
.top-cats li {
  display: inline;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.top-cats a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: inline;
  background: none;
  font: 13px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #484848;
  padding: 2px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.top-cats a:first-letter{text-transform: uppercase;}
ul{
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="top-cats">
  <li>Профессиональная химия</li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/mojuschie_i_opolaskivajuschie_sredstva">ОПОЛАСКИВАЮЩИЕ СРЕДСТВА</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/ruchnaja_mojkazamachivanie_posudy">РУЧНАЯ МОЙКА И ЧИСТКА ПОСУДЫ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/udalenie_izvestkovogo_naleta">УДАЛЕНИЕ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/ochistka_teplovogo_oborudovanija">ОЧИСТКА ТЕПЛОВОГО ОБОРУДОВАНИЯ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/ochistka_dezifektsija_i_uhod_za_poverhnostjami">ОЧИСТКА, ДЕЗИФЕКЦИЯ И УХОД ЗА ПОВЕРХНОСТЯМИ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/sanitarnye_mojuschie_sredstva">САНИТАРНЫЕ МОЮЩИЕ СРЕДСТВА</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/professionalnaja_himija_winterhalter">химия Winterhalter</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/catalog/dopolnitelnye_sredstva_dlja_uhoda">ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ СРЕДСТВА ДЛЯ УХОДА</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JSFiffle:** [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/NikitaSmith/jvnz026d/2/)